# SQL server string equality vs CHAR(0)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm facing a quite weird problem in SQL Server(version 12.0.2000.8, collation is Hungarian_CI_AS):
I have a table with a varchar(128) nullable column, which stores usernames,
and I simply can't match any of them with a simple '=' operator.
So when I execute a query like this:
`select * from myTable where username = 'john.doe'`,
it does not return any rows.

I found that when I select the same with LIKE and put a % as trailing char, so:
`select * from myTable where username = 'john.doe%'`,
it works fine.

So I've created a query which replaces all char(0)-s with '$' signs, looks like this:

```
select REPLACE(username, CHAR(0), '$') from myTable
where username LIKE 'john.doe%'
```

and it returns a 128 long literal, like this(stuffed with trailing $-s):
john.doe$$$$$$$$$$....

Considering the facts above, I suspected that somehow the char(0)-s are the problem, but when I run a simple query for simulating the same conditions for the '=' operator, I get that the 2 literals are equal:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ('john.doe') = ('john.doe' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(0) + CHAR(0)) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END
```

This query returns Equal.

So I'm completely confused, what is happening here?
And what should I do to make the '=' operator work on my database table?

Comment: For me your test query returns `Not Equal`, which is how it should be.

Comment: Well, the problem gets more complicated now. :) May I ask which version of sql server and what collation do you use?

Comment: It should not matter. Adding a trailing `char(0)` should make the string different. Comparison `=` ignores only trailing spaces, all other characters should be taken into account. I use SQL Server 2008 10.0.6000.29, Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Having zero characters in your text data will cause lots of problems - why not just remove them? `UPDATE myTable SET username = REPLACE(username, CHAR(0), '')`. Obviously backup the database first!!!

Comment: Well, I don't insert this zeros intentionally :) So updating the table once will not solve the problem, since new records are created continuously;Therefore I'd rather like to understand the root cause and fix it than updating the tables.

Comment: @user1307533, you should check your code that inserts the data, find why it appends zeroes and fix it. It is very unlikely that it is the server that appends these zeroes, it must be your code. Once the zeroes are in the data the database server behaves correctly when it does searches and comparisons - the value with trailing zeroes is not equal to the value without trailing zeroes.

Comment: As I said, i don't append zeros to the user names; athough I use linq, maybe it does. But why the hell it should do something like this? There are many other varchar columns in the database, but without the same problem..

Comment: Some update: using the unicode prefix on the string literal I can match in the columns; so username = N'john.doe' matches. But how can I force linq to sql queries to use the N prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the data type of the column in your table to nvarchar(128), instead of varchar(128). It might magically solve the problem (even if the queries will not use the N prefix), but I cannot explain why. It seems that there is a fundamental difference in handling of CHAR(0) between varchar and nvarchar data types.