# Can't concatenate to strings with CHAR(0) at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

The following snippets should demonstrate an issue I've observed in both SQL Server and in my VBScript web application:

```
SELECT '"Hello World"'
SELECT '"Hello World' + CHAR(0) + '"'
```

Results:

```
"Hello World"
"Hello World
```

Notice that the second result line is missing the final double quote.

I understand that you can't concatenate strings to a NULL value in SQL Server. However, the following snippet reveals that CHAR(0) is not considered NULL as far as SQL Server is concerned.

```
SELECT ISNULL(CHAR(0), 'CHAR(0) IS CONSIDERED NULL')
```

Result:

Also, when I read this value from the DB into a variable in VBScript, I'm unable to concatenate to that variable as well.

I'm not a C developer, but I understand that C-style strings are terminated by the null character. Is this relevant? Can someone please help me understand why this is happening in SQL Server and in VBScript?

I can solve my immediate problem by simply replacing all CHAR(0)'s in the offending data, but first I'd like to understand the reason for this and develop a preventative solution.

---

### EDIT: Including some VBScript

```
testSql = "SELECT '""Hello World' + CHAR(0) + '""' AS TestString"
set resultSet = conn.execute(testSql)
testString = resultSet.Fields.Item("TestString")

testString = testString & "}"

Response.Write testString
```

Result:

```
"Hello World
```

Comment: Where's the VBScript, all I see is SQL?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28362284/692942) might be relevant.

Comment: There is no VBScript in your question. VBScript uses BStr which have a header with the length. Windows uses C strings which are terminated with a null. All COM languages use the COM functions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms221236(v=vs.100). `msgbox Len("cat " & Chr(0) & "dog")` then `msgbox "cat " & Chr(0) & "dog"`. `MsgBox` is a wrapper around the API call `MessageBox`. A NULL is a valid character in a BStr but not in a C String.

Comment: @Noodles I'm not sure the OP even mentioned `MsgBox()` but okay.

Comment: It shows passing a valid Bstr to an API call it will be treated as a C string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server concatenates strings ending in nul characters just fine. See this example:

```
SELECT len('"Hello World' + CHAR(0) + '"')
```

Output:

```
14
```

SELECT len('"Hello World' + CHAR(0) + '"' + '"Hello World' + CHAR(0) + '"')

Output:

```
28
```

The result is the same when you store the string into a CTE or table first.

Its the handling and output in VB that makes it appear as if it does not. Try to print the length of the string your are getting out of SQL in VB.

Comment: That's interesting. I ran the SELECTS from my question through LEN in SSMS and, indeed, the output indicates that the concatenation occurred. However, when I execute those SELECTS from the original post in SSMS, the second double-quote in the second SELECT doesn't appear. So this is a "presentation" issue? An inability/unwillingness to render the rest of a string that contains the null character?

Comment: COM doesn't care either. Nothing to do with VBS. It's when a Windows API function is called.

Comment: @JimMcMaster Looks like it. You'd need to be careful with how you are handling the string. If it is manipulated by some code that stops at the nul char then you may end up with a truncated string.