# SQL Server concat empty string (not null)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to concat the columns here but when I encounter a column with empty / blank string, the concat failed.

I need to do some formatting for each column with different data type, so I am not using the CONCAT function. Using the conventional way like

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, [Priority]) + '~' + CONVERT(varchar,[AP_type]) + '~' + [AP_Name] + '~'
FROM table
```

Any suggestions on how I can concat empty string ?

Results I am looking :

```
0~0~~~~In~In
```

Thanks.

[image]

[image: tested concat]

Comment: Formatting is for the presentation layer, not SQL; this seems like a job for said application.

Comment: i need to concat the string and send to another application. there are workaround where i can do but i just want to see if there's a better solution that what i have in mind.

Comment: What does "the concat failed." mean? That gives no clue to your actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

1. always best to specify the length when converting to varchar.  For example varchar(50)
2. concat() will handle nulls as empty string and there is no need to convert.  Oddly enough, char(0) creates the odd behavior.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([priority] varchar(50),[ap_type] varchar(50),[ap_name] varchar(50),[ap_par] varchar(50),[infoText] varchar(50),[TxtCame] varchar(50),[TxtWent] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (0,0,'','','','In','In')
,(0,0,'','',null,'In','In')      -- Has Null
,(0,0,'','',char(0),'In','In')   -- Has Char(0) ... Truncates without NullIf()
 
Select NewString = concat(priority,'~',ap_type,'~',ap_name,'~',ap_par,'~',NullIf(infoText,char(0)),'~',TxtCame,'~',TxtWent)
from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewString
0~0~~~~In~In
0~0~~~~In~In
0~0~~~~In~In   -- NullIf() was required to fix
```

Comment: Typo: concat not convert

Comment: @Charlieface Thank for the catch!   I had convert on then brain :)

Comment: I tested this approach already but it won't handle "empty" string. updated the screenshot.

Comment: @user3015739 Sure it does.  Updated with an Example

Comment: @user3015739 what is the column length for colDataStr ?

Comment: length is 4000 

there's a special character in the column. ascii 0 which is null. no wonder i can't concat. the function failed to work too

https://i.imgur.com/ynTkpvi.png

Comment: @user3015739 the char(0) is the issue.  NULL does not cause an issue.   See Edit.  Added a NullIf()

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for your suggestion. I got some idea how to code this. In this column, I might have data, or empty string or null. At least I know it is not empty. Strange that SQL Server results should have show me it is NULL instead of empty

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640331/cant-concatenate-to-strings-with-char0-at-the-end) I think the NUL char is a client-side display issue